# Return to main view from navigation view and modal view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have views created in the way

main view -> modal view (navigation controller) -> navigation view root -> navigation view A

The modal view presentation style is default (coming up from the bottom), when modal view is dismissed (cancel action), it goes back to the bottom.

When navigation view A is pushed, it slides from right hand side as usual. When I dismiss the modal view from navigation view A, it also goes back to the bottom.

My question is, how can I dismiss modal view from navigation view A by sliding back to right?

The behave I am trying to achieve can be found on Microsoft bing app. When entering the setting page, it's presented as modal view. But for next levels in details (bookmarks, history ..), they are shown by navigation. Whenever done button in detail is pressed, the view slides (instead of going to bottom) and return to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs there are these possible styles available:

```
typedef enum {
   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
   UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
   UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
   UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

I think if these styles doesn't match your needs you have to create your animation yourself. Maybe this [correct link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) can help.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Those built-in styles have been tried, non of them does horizontal sliding for modal view. The link does not seem to work, would you check it again?

Answer (score 0):

I found the effect I am looking for can be achieved by using CATransition. The link has more details, http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13427-uiview-slide-transition.html